# How to Print Command output.txt line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to print an output file that reads decimal places and spaces in a list of numbers. If it has more or less than 2 decimal places and/or spaces in between the comma and number then the number is invalid and it is printed in the output text file. If it has 2 decimal places and no spaces in between number and comma then it is a Valid number and I is printed in the output text file.
Output file:
VALID    #it is only valid If float has two decimal places and no spaces
10.34,456.78

INVALID #it is only invalid if float has greater or less than two decimal places or it's an integer or if there's a whitespace in between number and comma
10.345, 45.678 (white space & it has 3 sig figs)

Create a file with numbers separated by commas
text file:

1,2.12,3.123

1,1.00

How many numbers does it pass the VALID sigfig filters.

```
from functools import reduce
res = 0
outfile = "output2.txt"
baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
index = 0
invalid_string = "INVALID"
valid_string = "VALID"
for line in open("file.txt"):               #for loop with variable line defined and using open() function to open the file inside the directory

    for line in open("file.txt"):               #for loop with variable line defined and using open() function to open the file inside the directory

        carrera = ''
        index = index +1                            #adds 1 for every line if it finds what the command wants

        print("Line {}: ".format(index))
        baconFile.write("Line {}:  ".format(index))

    with open('file.txt') as file:
        number_list = file.readline().strip().split(',')
        for line in number_list:
            if len(line.split('.')[-1]) == 2:
                #res += 1
##              print("VALID")

                carrera = valid_string 
            if len(line.split('.')[-1]) != 2:
                #res += 1
                carrera = invalid_string  

            print (carrera)
            baconFile.write(carrera + " ")
#print(res)
baconFile.close()


#For example, my list looks like this from my text file:
1,2.12,3.123
#Then it print out this to my output text file

output (decimal places from each number):
Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID
#However, if my list from my text file is like this:
1,2.12,3.123
1,1.00
#Then it print out this to my output text file
output: 
Line 1: Line 2:   INVALID 
VALID
INVALID
Line 3: Line 4:   INVALID
VALID
INVALID
#How do I get it to print out like this to my output text file:
Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID
LINE 2: INVALID VALID
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first example:

```
if '.' in number:
    res += len(number.split('.')[-1])
```

You're calculating the number of significant digits, then adding that number to `res`.  So of course you end up with the total number of significant digits from all the items.

If you just want to count **how many** items have exactly two significant digits, try this instead:

```
if '.' in number:
    if len(number.split('.')[-1]) == 2:
        res += 1
```

Comment: This worked great, I updated my code thanks!